# What is the execution order inside shiny observeEvent()?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to click a button, trigger insertUI, compute something, removeUI at the end. However, insertUI/removeUI take effect after the computation.

I am following the official example to dynamically update UI.
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

When adding Sys.sleep(2) after removeUI, it seems it is executed before removing the element.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"),
  textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "div:has(> #txt)"
    )
    Sys.sleep(2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What is the reason for this, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `immediate` argument.

```
removeUI(selector = "div:has(> #txt)", immediate = TRUE)
```